# Elasticsearch - Same search result for "and" and "ampersand"(&) in query

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

"**Designing an index in Elasticsearch so that "&" and "and" in query returns same result**"

How can we make Elasticsearch return same results whether the search was made with "**and**" as the query string or ampersand "**&**".

For example there's a query to look for all movie titles containing "**and / &**" in their name.

1. Mr. & Mrs. Smith
2. Jack and Jill
3. Abc and Def & ghi
4. Dummy Name

So in this case it shouldn't matter if the search is done with "and" or "&" in query should return 1,2,3.

***Dump from my Kibana Dev Tool***

PUT test_index
{
  "settings": {"number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc":
    {
      "properties": {
        "movie_name":{"type":"text"}
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
  "movie_name":"Mr. & Mrs. Smith"
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
  "movie_name":"Jack and Jill"
}

PUT /test_index/doc/3
{
  "movie_name":"Abc and Def & ghi"
}

PUT /test_index/doc/4
{
  "movie_name":"Dummy Name"
}

**Both the queries below should return the same result**

1. GET test_index/_search
   {
   "size": 20,
   "query": {
   "match": {
     "movie_name": "&"
   }
   }
   }
2. GET test_index/_search
   {
   "size": 20,
   "query": {
   "match": {
     "movie_name": "and"
   }
   }
   }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this

1. Use the *english* analyzer which will remove the special characters from your text and also the stop words like "and", so in essence your searches will be matched against the tokens without &/and hence will be the same. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/analysis-lang-analyzer.html for help doc
2. Keep your standard analyzer and add a character replacement filter to replace any occurrence of " & " pattern by " and ", then all those searches will emit the same tokens. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html for help doc

Comment: Thanks @ookboy24 I tried the second option, it works (I will paste the kibana dump below to help other people with similar problem). How does option 1 fit if you don't have those tokens because search is directly done on **&** or **and** .

Comment: PUT my_index
{
 ....
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "&",
          "replacement": "and"
...
  "mappings": {
 ...
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
..

PUT my_index/doc/1
{
  "movie_name":"Jack & Jill"
}


...
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "movie_name": "and"
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "+ => plus",
            "& => and"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you should create  char filter to do this.

When you create index with above analyzer

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "&"
}
```

output:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "and",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

and if you run the above analyse without the above char filter analyzer you will get

```
{
  "tokens": []
}
```

**Reason**:  In ES - the symbols are removed when you create field with Text type.

Comment: Thanks @Backtrack